# How can I check outside of spring, eg in Nginx, if user was authenticated by spring @EnableWebSecurity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, nginx, spring-security

In my java webapp I do security with standard spring-boot

`implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'`

```
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfig(...) : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http.csrf().disable().httpBasic().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER)
                .sessionFixation().changeSessionId()
                .and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(*dennyPatterns).denyAll()
                .antMatchers(*loginPatterns).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().formLogin().loginPage(loginUrl)
    }
}
```

How does it work under the hood?

How can I check in reverse proxy, eg Nginx, if request is made by an authenticated user?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can check the response code of the request to verify that the request was valid.